# How to find the original lead after it has been converted into an opportunity?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, leads, lead-conversion, convert

I've asked a similar question recently and got the answer I was looking for but still have a bit of a predicament.

In the call centre, agents take calls from technicians who sell new business to clients, they give all the information over the phone and we provide them with a lead ID as a reference. When we convert the lead into an opportunity (unless on a report where I can match the Lead ID to the converted opportunity) there is no way that I can find to discover the original lead information.

Basically what I am asking is, Is there a way to still have the lead information active on Salesforce? So if a query arises about the opportunity, we can go back to the lead page with all the information on as if it was freshly taken from the technician on the phone (before conversion)?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a setting on our system Salesforce or I am just being stupid. I can get a report with all the opportunities and the little tick box advising this was a converted lead. Even the lead ID but once it is converted it gets a new ID (the opportunity ID) What I want to be able to do is access the lead as if it was never converted. This is to match information up between the lead & opportunity as it seems when they are being converted some people seem to be amending information they shouldn't be. such as contact name/number/ lead source etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the lead is converted you would still have the original lead information. If you want to view it inside a lead report you need to add the filter `Converted = true.`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I am not sure if this is a setting on our system Salesforce or I am just being stupid. I can get a report with all the opportunities and the little tick box advising this was a converted lead. Even the lead ID but once it is converted it gets a new ID (the opportunity ID) What I want to be able to do is access the lead as if it was never converted. This is to match information up between the lead & opportunity as it seems when they are being converted some people seem to be amending information they shouldn't be. such as contact name/number/ lead source etc.

Comment: Did you try to create a report of type Lead with Converted Lead information?

Comment: Good call,  I have been using existing reports and customizing. I've used the Lead with converted lead information report and found everything I need. Thanks for your help! Have a great day